# Pandas - All Column to 1 new Column

Tags: python, pandas

My data frame has 6 columns of dates which i want them to in 1 column
[DATA FRAME IMAGE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4gKW.png)

Code to make another column is as below

```
df['Mega'] = df['Mega'].append(df['RsWeeks','RsMonths','RsDays','PsWeeks','PsMonths','PsDays'])
```

i am new to python and pandas i would like to learn more so please point me sources too as i am really bad with debugging as i have no programming background.

Comment: When you say you want to turn them into one column, do you mean you want a list of dates in each cell, or a string of all dates? Do you want the dates as datetime objects or strings?

Comment: i want list of dates in each cell , as later i want to filter them so i want those all dates in 6 columns into 1 big column to apply filter on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas documentation is a great source for good examples. [Click here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) to visit a page with a lot of examples and visuals.

For your particular case:

We construct a sample `DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
  {"RsWeeks": "2015-11-10", "RsMonths": "2016-08-01"},
  {"RsWeeks": "2015-11-11", "RsMonths": "2015-12-30"}
])
print("DataFrame preview:")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
DataFrame preview:
      RsWeeks    RsMonths
0  2015-11-10  2016-08-01
1  2015-11-11  2015-12-30
```

We concatenate the columns `RsWeeks` and `RsMonths` to create a `Series`:

```
my_series = pd.concat([df["RsWeeks"], df["RsMonths"]], ignore_index=True)
print("\nSeries preview:")
print(my_series)
```

Output:

```
Series preview:
0    2015-11-10
1    2015-11-11
2    2016-08-01
3    2015-12-30
```

## Edit

If you really need to add the new `Series` as a column to your `DataFrame`, you can do the following:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Mega": my_series})
df = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)
print("\nDataFrame preview:")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
DataFrame preview:
      RsWeeks    RsMonths        Mega
0  2015-11-10  2016-08-01  2015-11-10
1  2015-11-11  2015-12-30  2015-11-11
2         NaN         NaN  2016-08-01
3         NaN         NaN  2015-12-30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.melt()` which makes your dataframe from wide to long:

```
df_reshaped = pd.melt(df, id_vars = ['id_1','id_2','id_3'], var_name = 'new_name', value_name = 'Mega')
```

Comment: Don't one need to add `.str` after column names?

Comment: I always use ```.astype(str)```, will it work with just ```.str``` ?

Comment: Well by this all my columns get into one row. but my objective is to convert all those columns to independent rows so that was i will get some  24 rows. because i want to later run filter on that mega column

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought you needed. What is your ideal output?

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/bD0iLMdl  i want my columns to look like this in end so i could use filter on this late 254 rows column to filter resutls

Comment: OK I know what you need. Do you have other variables in the dataframe? that you don't need to make into 1 column?

Comment: no these are all i want to convert, rest of of the columns are not wanted which i guess i can drop and just keep these 6 old and 1 mega new one

Comment: try ```pd.melt``` in the answer above and let me know.

Comment: after the melt i get this output https://www.screencast.com/t/IYAq0Bj6g3 this looks like essentially dropping the columns but the objective of getting those columns into 1 still remains, Please dont mind if m asking something foolish i just started 3 days abck

Comment: it's okay to ask. But I think check out the documentation of melt, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html, and see some examples. I think if you tweak it a bit you will get what you want.

Comment: Thanks will check

Answer (score 0):

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"name" : 'Dav Las Oms'.split(),
                  'age' : [25, 50,  70]})
df['Name'] = list(['a', 'M', 'm'])
```

df:

```
  name  age Name
0  Dav   25    a
1  Las   50    M
2  Oms   70    m
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.astype(str).apply('|'.join, axis=1))
```

df:

```
          0
0  Dav|25|a
1  Las|50|M
2  Oms|70|m
```